# Why is my jsp struts2 sx:textarea rendering only as a horizontal bar instead of the expected input field?

Tags: ajax, jsp, dojo, struts2, textarea

I started out trying to follow this tutorial to create a [Rich Text Editor](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/richeditor.shtml).

I quickly realized that the tutorial was outdated and I needed to use the struts2-dojo-plugin.

My JSP now looks like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Pagination Example</title>
<sx:head parseContent="true"/> 
<link href="<s:url value="/assets/css/main.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form>
        <sx:textarea id="pasteTextInput" name="text" label="Paste your text here" cols="50" rows="50" />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to render this page, instead of the desired rich text editor, or even any text area element, all I get is a little horizontal bar.

This is the relevant CSS:

```
// /assets/css/main.css
#pasteTextInput
{
    background-color: #fcfcfc; 
    border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    min-height: 500px;
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

and this is the HTML that is created by the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Pagination Example</title>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
    // Dojo configuration
    djConfig = {
        isDebug: false,
        bindEncoding: "UTF-8"
          ,baseRelativePath: "/OverviewOfStruts/struts/dojo/"
          ,baseScriptUri: "/OverviewOfStruts/struts/dojo/"
         ,parseWidgets : true

    };
</script> 



  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/OverviewOfStruts/struts/dojo/struts_dojo.js"></script> 

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/OverviewOfStruts/struts/ajax/dojoRequire.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/OverviewOfStruts/struts/xhtml/styles.css" type="text/css"/> 

<script language="JavaScript" src="/OverviewOfStruts/struts/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script language="JavaScript" src="/OverviewOfStruts/struts/xhtml/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script language="JavaScript" src="/OverviewOfStruts/struts/css_xhtml/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<link href="/OverviewOfStruts/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="paginationExample" name="paginationExample" action="/OverviewOfStruts/paginationExample.action" method="post">

<table class="wwFormTable">

        <textarea dojoType="Editor2"
 items="linkGroup;|;textGroup;|;justifyGroup;|;listGroup;|;indentGroup;|;colorGroup"
 name="text" cols="50" rows="50" id="pasteTextInput"></textarea> 


    </table></form>









</body>

</html>
```

Is there something else I need to do for this to work?

I saw on [this guide to updating from struts 2.0 to struts 2.1](https://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/troubleshooting-guide-migrating-from-struts-20x-to-21x.html#TroubleshootingguidemigratingfromStruts2.0.xto2.1.x-AjaxTheme%252FDojo) something about adding dependencies, but I couldn't figure out where to add this.  (For whatever its worth, I'm ***NOT*** using Maven.)

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using?  I ask because some of the properties in `djConfig` there look like properties that haven't existed in `djConfig` for 4 years (since before Dojo 1.0).  It's quite possible it's not even parsing your textarea into a widget.  Why not start here?  http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Editor

Comment: @Ken - I've got struts2-dojo-plugin-2.2.1.jar  ... From what I can see in the HTML above, it looks like the sx:textarea in the JSP is becoming the textarea in the HTML... but I don't see why only a horizontal line is displaying.  I'll check out that link though, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: it is doing that because I am using Chrome.

It renders very differently in different browsers, and considerably more effectively in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

It seems that using this is a really bad solution for a WYSIWYG text editor.

Ken's solution seems much better.